# How to reset a cloud Postgres DB as if it was just created before each demo deployment?

Tags: postgresql, deployment

I was using Heroku for projects in development.

Heroku has a great option to reset Postgres DB: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-reset.

Now I'm using other cloud services for Postgres hosting which don't have such feature.

Since during the development phases the DB can change considerably I would like to automatically reset the DB during each deployment before being filled again by my new code.

How do I reset the DB (as if it was just created) if the hosting doesn't provide me a CLI/API to do it but only a web interface and of course the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

That will be rather cumbersome. Here is a (probably incomplete) list:

- drop all schemas except `public` with `CASCADE`
- drop all extensions except `plpgsql` with `CASCADE`
- drop all tables, views, functions, materialized views, procedures, sequences, operators, languages, aggregates, collations, casts, conversions, domains, foreign tables, text search configurations, text search dictionaries, text search parsers and types in the `public` schema with `CASCADE`
- drop all large objects
- drop all subscriptions, publications, foreign data wrappers and event triggers in the database
- alter all default privileges back to the original
- use `ALTER DATABASE ... RESET` and `ALTER ROLE ... IN DATABASE ...` to undo all settings on the database level